# Integral of power mean function

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I wonder, is there a closed-form solution to integral of type 
$$\int \left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x}dx,$$
for $a\ne b$ (both positive real numbers). If not, what about a special case when $a=1$, i.e., $$\int \left(\frac{1+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x}dx.$$

In general, having a definite integral of this type, are there some methods to compute such integrals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such a closed form were to exist, then, for $a=\dfrac1b=e$, we'd have $\displaystyle\int\sqrt[\Large x]{\cosh x}~dx=F(x)$. Now, are you aware of the former expression possessing any closed form anti-derivatives ? In fact, even simpler integrands, like $x^x$ or $\sqrt[\Large x]x$, do not have one. Even the simple case as $b=0$, for instance, requires the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). Of course, all of this is merely an informal explanation. An actual proof would require applying either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)), or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). The latter consists basically in an entire book, and the former requires deep knowledge of notions of [abstract algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra).